# Load javascript function for a div solely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div scroll horizontally and another one vertically(actually the rest of them), but I don't know how to use a certain piece of code for only one div.

```
    (function() {
function scrollHorizontally(e) {
    e = window.event || e;
    var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    document.body.scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
    e.preventDefault();
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
    // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
    window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
    // Firefox
    window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
} else {
    // IE 6/7/8
    window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
}
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27mjq1ue/1/

I want "div1" to scroll horizontally and "div2 - div5" vertically, but the code I have applies to the whole document.

**To sum it up:**
I access the website > I scrolldown, on scrolldown div1 scrolls horizontally > when div1 is done scrolling, div2 starts scrolling vertically > div3, div4, div5 also scroll vertically after that.

Comment: Can you precise your need? Even fiddle doesn't help to realize which behaviour you're expecting. _Which_ mouse action should have _which_ effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle by adding an if check for what the target of the scroll event is, if it is div1, then scroll horizontally, otherwise do nothing, meaning let the default scroll behavior occur.

```
if (e.target.id === 'div1') {
  ...
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mxrnrr4a/1/)

Comment: I only recently really started working with javascript and am not super familiar with adding event handlers, but it would seem that you may be able to add this handler directly to `div1` instead of the window. This way the if check wouldn't be necessary and would just work.

Comment: it worked, thanks. I have to practice my "javascript way of thinking"